# "erupted into wild cheer/cheering"

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-choice

> - As the band got on stage, the crowd went wild.
> - As the band got on stage, the crowd erupted into wild cheers/cheering.

What is the most natural way to phrase the second sentence if I want a similar meaning as the first sentence? Should it be "into wild cheers" or "into wild cheering" or something third?

Comment: A *wild **cheer*** works.

Comment: Both will be understood.  *Cheering* sounds better but *cheers* also works.

Comment: [Both verb form are extremely common](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=erupted+into+wild+cheers%2Cerupted+into+wild+cheering&year_start=1950&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3) - about equally common, as that NGram chart shows.

Comment: Is there any difference between them?